# Building APK failed eas

Tags: react-native, gradle, build, expo

[stderr]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

[stderr]

- What went wrong:

[stderr]

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-pdf-lib:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease'.

[stderr]

> Could not create task ':react-native-pdf-lib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

[stderr]

> In order to compile Java 9+ source, please set compileSdkVersion to 30 or above

[stderr]

- Try:

[stderr]

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

[stderr]

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[stderr]

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

[stderr]

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

[stderr]

BUILD FAILED in 3m 12s

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

5 actionable tasks: 5 executed

Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

I actually doesn't know what to do. I have android/app/build.gradle i changed the compilesdk version to 30

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

so... technically, there's one thing to clarify: if you're building from your computer, it definitely won't work... at least that's how it is for me. It usually only works with EAS build and GitHub Actions, both of which use Ubuntu (Linux) machines to generate the final application.
So, if you're using your computer, try using EAS build or GitHub Actions (feel free to ask, and I'll send you everything you need).

If that's not the case, my first advice is to look at `react-native-pdf-lib`; it might have some issues. Maybe you haven't installed it correctly, or the version is deprecated.
So essentially, try to resolve it, and if it doesn't work, try removing it using `npm uninstall react-native-pdf-lib` or `yarn remove react-native-pdf-lib` and then try again...
In my opinion, the potential issue might be with mismatched versions.

Some might suggest trying something else; I'll direct you to a possible [question here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62379152/could-not-determine-the-dependencies-of-task-appmergedebugassets) that might help you.